# How to install extension using composer - Magento EE 2.2 ( Production )

Tags: magento2.2, magento2-enterprise

I am having issue with few extension installation on Magento EE 2.2 production server. Extension works fine on my local system but when i push code to production it gives error Fatal error:

> Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Vendor\Module\Api\StockistRepositoryInterface

I tried 2 methods for module installation:

**Method 1 ( using manual upload ):** copy module into app/code and then pushed the code to server, deployment goes fine and in system->configurations i am able to save configurations but when i try to access module sections ( to add entries ) it gives error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Vendor\Module\Api\StockistRepositoryInterface in /app/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:111 Stack trace: #0 /app/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(108): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Vendor\Module...', Array) #1 /app/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(150): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Limesharp\Stock...') #2 /app/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(79): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->get('Limesharp\Stock...') #3 /app/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(56): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Limesharp\Stock...', Array) #4 /app/vendor/magento/framework/App/ActionFactory.php(40): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Limesharp\Stock...') #5 /app/vendor/magento/framework/App/Router/Base.php(297): Mage in /app/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 111

**Method 2 ( using composer ) :**

Run command  composer require vendor/module-name

After composer is installed and updated , pushed only composer files to production server, deployment goes fine but still getting same error. ( able to save configurations but can't add entries ).

**NOTE** : before pushing composer files i deleted module folder from app/code.

This issue is with couple of modules and don't know how to fix that issue. module work fine on local but not on production server.

help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Its a bug with the module you have. The StockistRepositoryInterface probably does not have any preference to a model.

Comment: I have checked that module's di.xml file there is no issue , secondly same issue is with couple of other modules

Comment: Have you cleared you generation folder? They have moved from ```var/di``` to ```root-folder/generation```.

Comment: Yes did that too.